# How to conditionally go to the next page in pageViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am using pageViewController in my App. I have 9 pages which are created dymanically and each page have 1 question which have 4 multiple choice answers. Each option have custom UIButton with image and its "BlankedCheckBox" when the option is not selected and "MakredCheckBox" when its selected. Right now I can go to next page even if any of the available answer is not selected. I want to go to the next page only if user has selected one of the available option. The transition style of my pageViewController is scroll. 
It seems to me like I have to add something in following method. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController *) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index ++;

    if (index == [self.questionTitles count]) {
        return  nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not implement the `dataSource` methods. If you do the user can scroll using a gesture.

To achieve the behavior you want, set the page in code in the `IBAction` of the control:

```
- (IBAction)nextPage {
    [self setViewControllers:[nextViewController]
             direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
              animated:YES
            completion:nil];
}
```